# Syncing with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, synchronization

I have the following setup : local AD synced with Office365 through Synchronization Service Manager (AAD).

When I installed Azure Sync service on my W2008R2 server, the installer created a scheduled task which is actually working.

The problem is that scheduled task is only running the following operations :

"Delta Import" and "Delta Synchronization"

Whenever these tasks run, no changes are actually made to my Office365. I have to run a manual "Export" operation through the software so the changes are taken into account in Office365.

I would like to know if I can make a script or anything else to automate the "Export" task.

I have already tried to run the command DirectorySyncClientCmd.exe initial but it has the same effect, I have to manually run the Export command so the changes are really pushed into Office365.

Thanks in advance, have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is in "Staging Mode", which is for the initial installation of Azure Sync.

If you run the "Azure AD Connect" you should see the option to **Configure Stating Mode** - and set it to "Disabled".

The Export option will then be enabled.